# Не получается подключить библиотеку в Visual Stidio С#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: Проблема , как на картинке]
Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой:не могу подключить библиотеку в Visual Stidio. Библиотека TweetSharp , скачана с этого сайта:https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetSharp-Unofficial/. Выводит сообщение , как на скриншоте. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А почему вы так странно ставите Nuget пакеты?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Файл с расширением .nupkg не является сборкой, поэтому вы его и не можете добавить в ссылки. Используйте менеджер пакетов NuGet для таких целей.

Например, можете кликнуть ПКМ по проекту в Обозревателе решений, затем по Управление пакетами NuGet, найти нужный и установить. Ссылка будет добавлена автоматически.

Comment: Простите за мою неграмотность) Только учусь , спасибо, все заработало

Comment: Если хотите отблагодарить, примите ответ, это можно сделать слева =)